# Angular вызов при изменений переменной

Tags: angular4, angular5

Angular > 4

Есть такая строчка кода

```
<ngx-ebar-treemo *ngIf="type=='Bar' && graphic" type1="{{type1}}" type2="{{type2}}"></ngx-ebar-treemo>
```

который вызывает компонент. мне надо вызовать при каждом изменение переменных type1 и type2.

Помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
```

И метод:

```
     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     //TODO: Делайте всё что вам нужно
     }
```

Метод ngOnChanges() вызывается перед методом ngOnInit() и при изменении свойств в привязке. С помощью параметра SimpleChanges в методе можно получить текущее и предыдущее значение измененного свойства

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Тоже нашел. Но проблема в том что это простая функция и там меняю преременную  tonclick_checks(id)   {
     this.type1 = id;
    }       И у дочерней он не меняет в этом случай

Comment: Меняет только когда типа емиттера есть что то

Comment: или (click) когда есть

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях, когда `ngOnChanges` по разным причинам не подходит, а вызвать изменения нужно, используют сеттеры и геттеры. Подход заключается в том, что все изменения происходят с переменными.

Была у вас, к примеру, переменная `type1` объявлена таким образом:

```
type1 = 0;
```

Вы меняете это на:

```
_type1 = 0; // именно со знаком подчёркивания.
set type1(val: number) { // val - это значение, которое присваиваем
                         // в переменную _type1.

  this.some_method(val); // Вызываете какую-то функцию, которая
                         // должна отрабатывать при изменении
                         // значения переменной.

  this._type1 = val; // Собственно изменяете значение самой переменной.
}
get type1(): number { // Геттер просто возвращает значение и больше ничего.
  return this._type1;
}
```

Плюс подхода в том, что далее в коде программы к переменной обращаетесь так же, как и ранее: `this.type1`, при этом при присвоении ей нового значения будет отрабатывать функция `this.some_method(val);`.

Вот [тут немного подробнее об употреблении геттеров и сеттеров](http://dev.hive.pro/courses/angular-6/03-lokalnoe-khranilische-komponent-izbrannye/page-3#copmaring-methods). По-русски, с листингом и репозиторием.

Вам, видимо, это уже поздно, но надеюсь кому-нибудь с подобной проблемой это поможет.